# Python/Cassandra loading error

Tags: python, cassandra

I am getting a key error 0. This is what I am doing:

```
import sys
def main():
    import csv
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
    cluster= Cluster()
    session = cluster.connect('casspoc')
    with open('C:\Users\krispc\Downloads\HPI_master.csv','rb') as csvfile:
        rd = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in rd:
              session.execute("insert into fhadata(hpi_type, hpi_flavor, freq, level ,place_name, place_id, yr, period,index_nsa, index_sa)values('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}',{},{},{},{})".format(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[11],row[12],row[13],row[14],row[15],row[16],row[17]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())


my table 

CREATE TABLE fhadata (
    hpi_type text,
    hpi_flavor text,
    freq text,
    level text,
    place_name text ,
    place_id text,
    yr int,
    period int,
    index_nsa float,
    index_sa float,    PRIMARY KEY (hpi_type, hpi_flavor, freq, level));
```

Thank you for your help.

Krish

Comment: Hi. Please indent all your code four spaces from the left margin. Otherwise, it's unreadable. An easy way to do this is to highlight the code and then click the "{}" in the tool bar above the edit window.

Comment: If it's complaining about a key value of 0, I would guess that's being triggered by the "row[0]" expression in the insert statement. You could try assuming that the key values start with 1 instead of 0. Or dump out row to find out what the key values actually are.